# How to write an R function to create a new column in any dataframe from conditional values of two existing columns?

Tags: r, function

#### Problem:

I am having a fairly frustrating problem. I am trying to write a function that would create/populate a new column within any given dataframe based off of the values within two already existing columns of that dataframe.

#### Context:

I frequently work with a database that references events with two dimensions (project ID (1-7) and localeID(de_DE, fr_FR, jp_JP, etc...).

```
projectId    localeId
1            jp_JP   
2            es_ES       
3            de_DE         
1            jp_JP       
2            es_ES          
3            de_DE
```

I have to perform ETL from the database and create a new "market" dimension that is based off the projectId and localeID. For example, projectId of 1 and a localeId of jp_JP could mean that the market is "JAPAN1".

```
 projectId localeId   market
         1    jp_JP   JAPAN1
         2    es_ES   SPAIN2
         3    au_AU     AUS3
         4    us_US      US4
         5    en_EN ENGLAND5
         6    de_DE GERMANY6
```

#### Current Successful Code:

Write now I have a long winded piece of R code using ifelse functions. I.E....

```
df$market <- ifelse(df$localeId == "jp_JP" & df$projectId == '1', "JAPAN1")
df$market <- ifelse(df$localeId == "es_ES" & df$projectId == '10', "SPAIN10")
```

This is...fine. It gets the job done. Unfortunately I have a lot of scripts that deal with this market feature and I don't want to copy paste this ifelse code over and over. Instead I want to write a function that can be used on any dataframe to create a new market column based off the localeId and projectId.

#### Attempted/Failed Solutions:

```
market_names <- function(df, "market", "projectId", "localeId"){
             df$market <- NA 
             x <- ifelse(projectId == 1, "1",
                     ifelse(projectId == 2, "2", projectId)
             y <- ifelse(localeId == "jp_JP", "JAPAN",
                     ifelse(localeId == "es_ES", "SPAIN", localeId)
            for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
                 df[i,]$market <- paste(x,y, sep = "")
}

df <- market_names(df, "market", "projectId", "localeId")
```

Unfortunately the code just breaks down and won't even run when I attempt to pass a dataframe to the function.

#### Request:

I'm hoping somebody on here has experienced similar issues and could offer advice on how to fix this function so that it could be used for any dataframe at any time. I always have the same dimensions of projectId and localeId, so I thought this would save me a lot of time in the future.

If you think that there is an easier way to do all of this without even a function I'd love to hear your thoughts, as well!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the result from `dput(head(df))` to the bottom of your question. Will help to answer it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I added the input/desired output at the top of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't work for a number of reasons. For example, you are missing closing parentheses on your `ifelse`s. The closing curly bracket on your function definition is also missing. The `x` and `y` variables in your for-loop are vectors with length > 1, so they need indices, too. The arguments should not be strings alone, they should be assigned to variables that can be referenced within the function. Your nested `ifelse`s only deal with two cases each: 1 and 2, and JAPAN and SPAIN. Lastly, your function doesn't return anything. After fixing those things you end up with this:

```r
market_names <- function(df){
    df$market <- NA
    x <- ifelse(df$projectId == 1, "1",
                ifelse(df$projectId == 2, "2", df$projectId))
    y <- ifelse(df$localeId == "jp_JP", "JAPAN",
                ifelse(df$localeId == "es_ES", "SPAIN", df$localeId))
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
        df[i,]$market <- paste(x[i],y[i], sep = "")
    }
    df
}

market_names(df)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  projectId localeId market
      <dbl> <chr>    <chr> 
1         1 jp_JP    1JAPAN
2         2 es_ES    2SPAIN
3         3 au_AU    3au_AU
4         4 us_US    4us_US
5         5 en_EN    5en_EN
6         6 de_DE    6de_DE
```

It's obvious `x` should be after why `y` in `paste`. Your conditions also need to handle all cases better.

It would probably be easiest to just use a list of country codes mapped to country names. The column `localeId` can then be used as an index. Neither loops nor conditions are necessary:

```r
# Country proper names can be accessed using codes.
country_codes <- list("jp_JP" = "JAPAN",
                      "es_ES" = "SPAIN",
                      "de_DE" = "GERMANY",
                      "au_AU" = "AUS",
                      "us_US" = "US",
                      "en_EN" = "ENGLAND",
                      "de_DE" = "GERMANY"
                      )

# Pass in dataframe and country codes.
market_names <- function(df, country_codes){
    df$market <- paste0(unlist(country_codes[df$localeId], use.names = F),
                        df$projectId
                        )
    df
}

# Function call:
market_names(df, country_codes)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  projectId localeId market  
      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
1         1 jp_JP    JAPAN1  
2         2 es_ES    SPAIN2  
3         3 au_AU    AUS3    
4         4 us_US    US4     
5         5 en_EN    ENGLAND5
6         6 de_DE    GERMANY6
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate you walking me through the function creation here. This is exactly what I was trying to do and I've been able to repurpose it for the full dataset!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a slight change in methodology instead of just making code that is slightly easier to write. When I am creating lookup tables I prefer to save them somewhere as a table in a database or as a csv file on a hard drive. This is because I will often use/alter them again in the future. Once you have a lookup table you can do a left_join or a merge to combine the data. I'm familiar with the left_join so I'll use that below. If you need to use base-R then someone else may be able to help with that part.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

# The original data you input
df1 <- readr::read_csv(
  "projectId,    localeId
  1,            jp_JP   
  2,            es_ES       
  3,            de_DE         
  1,            jp_JP       
  2,            es_ES          
  3,            de_DE"
)

# A lookup table, often loaded from a file
# It is common to create a lookup table in excel and save it as a csv to import
df_lookup <- readr::read_csv(
  "projectId, localeId,   market
         1,    jp_JP,   JAPAN1
         2,    es_ES,   SPAIN2
         3,    au_AU,     AUS3
         4,    us_US,      US4
         5,    en_EN, ENGLAND5
         6,    de_DE, GERMANY6"
)

# A join (dplyr) or a merge (base)
df2 <- left_join(df1,df_lookup,by = c("projectId","localeId"))

df2
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# projectId localeId market
#       <dbl> <chr>    <chr> 
# 1         1 jp_JP    JAPAN1
# 2         2 es_ES    SPAIN2
# 3         3 de_DE    NA    
# 4         1 jp_JP    JAPAN1
# 5         2 es_ES    SPAIN2
# 6         3 de_DE    NA
```

Notice that 3, de_DE resulted in NA because I don't have that value in my lookup table.

Another way to do this would potentially be to have a lookup table for localeId to localeName and then `paste0(localeName,projectId)`.

**EDIT:**

It looks like you mentioned pasting things together so here's that methodology using the dplyr left_join.

```
df_lookup2 <- readr::read_csv(
  "localeId, localeName
 jp_JP,  Japan
 es_ES,  Spain
 au_AU,  Australia
 us_US,  US
 en_EN, England
 de_DE, Germany"
)

# Using dplyr pipes
df3 <- left_join(df1,df_lookup2,by = c("localeId")) %>%
  mutate(market = paste0(localeName,projectId)) %>%
  select(-localeName)

df3
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# projectId localeId market  
#       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
# 1         1 jp_JP    Japan1  
# 2         2 es_ES    Spain2  
# 3         3 de_DE    Germany3
# 4         1 jp_JP    Japan1  
# 5         2 es_ES    Spain2  
# 6         3 de_DE    Germany3

# Using dplyr join, but base remainder
df4 <- left_join(df1,df_lookup2,by = c("localeId"))
df4$market <- paste0(df4$localeName,df4$projectId)
df4 <- df4[,c("projectId","localeId","market")]

df4
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# projectId localeId market  
#       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
# 1         1 jp_JP    Japan1  
# 2         2 es_ES    Spain2  
# 3         3 de_DE    Germany3
# 4         1 jp_JP    Japan1  
# 5         2 es_ES    Spain2  
# 6         3 de_DE    Germany3
```

Comment: I was thinking about this method, as you are totally correct; it is so much easier to just have a table with the relationships on hand for joining. Thank you for the solution!